# Bulk Append text to all *.db files in folder (cPanel bulk DNS Insert)

Tags: bind

I run my own DNS cluster using 1 server running cPanel/WHM and 4 servers (ns1-ns4) running cPanel DNS Only.

I've just added the 4th DNS Only server (ns4.domain.com) but the problem is that all 200 of my current zone files do not contain the newly added nameserver.

So even though all of my 4 nameservers have the proper zone files on them to serve dns queries for all of my domains each zone file only lists 3 of my nameservers like the following:

```
example.com.    86400   IN  SOA ns1.domain.com. domains.domain.com. (
                    2013081402 ;Serial Number
                    86400 ;refresh
                    7200 ;retry
                    2419200 ;expire
                    86400 ;minimum
)
example.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.domain.com.
example.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.domain.com.
example.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns3.domain.com.
example.com.    3600    IN  A   11.22.33.44
localhost   3600    IN  A   127.0.0.1
example.com.    14400   IN  MX  0   example.com.
mail    14400   IN  CNAME   example.com.
www 14400   IN  CNAME   example.com.
ftp 14400   IN  CNAME   example.com.
```

I would like to be able to mass edit/add my new nameserver (ns4.domain.com) to all of the zone files in /var/named/*.db so all zone files should have NS records like the following

```
example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.domain.com.
example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.domain.com.
example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns3.domain.com.
example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns4.domain.com.
```

The only thing is im not sure how to add this line of text to all of the zone files. I know how to replace and was thinking of doing something along the following but i don't think this would work due to not having the new line.

```
replace "example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns3.domain.com." "example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns3.domain.com.
example.com. 86400   IN  NS  ns4.domain.com." -- /var/named/*.db
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The order of resource records in a zone file is mostly arbitrary, simply append the new records at the end.

Don't forget to update the serial number though!

Comment: Im not sure how i can append the new records at the end of all the zones without having to manually go through each of the 200 zones. Is there some function that works like "replace" but will just append text to all -- /var/named/*.db ? I have looked up how to update the serials when im done though :)

Comment: @Matthew_Ife posted a script below but typically an append is nothing more than `echo "something" >> file` and enclosing that in a loop: `for file in *.db ; do echo "something" >> $file ; done` should be trivial scripting.

Answer (score 0):

This will manipulate the zone file in such a way that it will add the correct serial number and append the right nameserver.

You need to call the script for every zone file. You can use `find` or a shell loop of a glob to do this.

This relies on the format of the serial number being such that it contains "; Serial Number" on the line.
It also expects the domain name to be declared as the first word on the first line.
Finally it expects the nameserver declared in "$LASTNS" To be there. You can change the value before running the script though.

Oh and running this script against a zonefile already manipulated by the script will break the zonefile. There is a simple test to fix this but will leave you to work that out.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

LASTNS="ns3.domain.com."
NEWNS="ns4.domain.com."
WORKDIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/addns.XXXXXXXX)

function cleanup
{
  if [ -n "${WORKDIR}" -a -d "${WORKDIR}" ]; then
    rm -fr "${WORKDIR}"
  fi
}

function new_serial_no
{
  local old=$1
  local olddate="${old:0:8}"
  local newdate=$(date "+%Y%m%d")

  ## Figure out if the revision number needs to be bumped or if we override
  ## with a new date.
  if [[ $olddate == $newdate ]]; then
     newdate="${newdate}"$(printf "%02d" "$((${old:8:2}+1))")
     echo $newdate
  else
    echo ${newdate}00
  fi
}

trap cleanup EXIT

ZONEFILE=$1

if [ -z "${ZONEFILE}" -o ! -f "${ZONEFILE}" ]; then
  echo "Requires a zonefile as input" >&2
  exit 1
fi

DOMAIN=$(head -n1 "${ZONEFILE}" | cut -d " " -f1)
SERIAL=$(grep ";Serial Number" "${ZONEFILE}" | egrep -o "[0-9]+")
NEWSERIAL=""

if [ -z "${DOMAIN}" -o -z "${SERIAL}" ]; then
  echo "Could not find matching domain or serial number" >&2
  exit 1
fi

NEWSERIAL=$(new_serial_no "${SERIAL}")
if [ -z "${NEWSERIAL}" ]; then
  echo "Could not determine new serial number" >&2
  exit 1
fi

## Have enough now to manipulate the file
cp -p "${ZONEFILE}" "${WORKDIR}/zone"
sed -ie "/${LASTNS}/a${DOMAIN}    86400   IN  NS  ${NEWNS}" "${WORKDIR}/zone"
sed -ie "s/${SERIAL}/${NEWSERIAL}/" "${WORKDIR}/zone"
NEWZONE=$(mktemp -u "${ZONEFILE}.XXXXXXX")
cp -p "${WORKDIR}/zone" "${NEWZONE}"
mv "${NEWZONE}" "${ZONEFILE}"
```